# Change <td> width without table-fixed

Tags: css

I want to change the width of one of my cell but without to fixed all table cells. Is there any way to change specific `<td>` without the rule `table-fixed`

Comment: use a class for the specific td

Comment: One way i can think of is using [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_td_colspan.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Give the td a class name. Like `<TD CLASS="class">cel</TD>`
Then in css call it like `.class {color:red}`

https://jsfiddle.net/tnquk2xt/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the table cell and style it appropriately like so:

CSS

```
.large {width:150px;}
.small {width: 50px;}
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="small">First</td>
  <td class="large">Second</td>
  <td class="small">Third</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmvbmktn/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_width

```
<td width="70%">
```

It was not really hard to find, they set width of the 2 TDs but it works also with only one TD width.

Use Google !! :3